# How to present crossDissolve view in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios13

In UIKit I used below code to present a modal Viewcontroller with presentation style **crossDissolve**

```
controller.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But how I can achieve this in swiftUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an extension on UIViewController like this:

```swift
struct ViewControllerHolder {
    weak var value: UIViewController?
}

struct ViewControllerKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: ViewControllerHolder {
        return ViewControllerHolder(value: UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController)

    }
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var viewController: UIViewController? {
        get { return self[ViewControllerKey.self].value }
        set { self[ViewControllerKey.self].value = newValue }
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    func present<Content: View>(style: UIModalPresentationStyle = .automatic, transitionStyle: UIModalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical, @ViewBuilder builder: () -> Content) {
        let toPresent = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(EmptyView()))
        toPresent.modalPresentationStyle = style
        toPresent.modalTransitionStyle = transitionStyle
        toPresent.rootView = AnyView(
            builder()
                .environment(\.viewController, toPresent)
        )
        self.present(toPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and use it as you want in your SwiftUI code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.viewController) private var viewControllerHolder: UIViewController?
    private var viewController: UIViewController? {
        self.viewControllerHolder
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.viewController?.present(style: .fullScreen, transitionStyle: .coverVertical) {
              Text("OK")
           }
        }) {
           Text("Present me!")
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, you have an ability to change your presentation and transition style as you want

Comment: How can I change the background colour of viewcontroller?

Comment: In Present func in `UIViewContrller` extension you can change it like `toPresent.view.backgroundColor = yourColor`

Comment: @Mac3n How to dismiss this viewcontroller?

Comment: set `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode` in your presented view controller and then when you want to dismiss it call `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`

Comment: @Mac3n But not working in my code. Here is my code - https://github.com/shamiul110107/Modal-Presentation-with-transparent-background-and-crossDissolve-style-in-swiftUI

Comment: Change your variable to `@Environment(\.viewController) private var viewControllerHolder: UIViewController?` and call this in your button action : `self.viewControllerHolder?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: navigation links are not working with this view?

Comment: @Mac3n Is there any way to access SwiftUI View in present<Content: View>(style) method?