# How to present a full screen AVPlayerViewController in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, avplayerviewcontroller

In SwiftUI, it seems like the best way to set up an AVPlayerViewController is to use the UIViewControllerRepresentable in a fashion somewhat like this...

```
struct PlayerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var videoURL: URL?


    private var player: AVPlayer {
        return AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
    }


    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller =  AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        controller.player = player
        controller.player?.play()
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ playerController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {

    }
}
```

However from the documentation that the only way to show this controller in a full-screen way is to present it using a sheet.

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showingDetail) {
    PlayerViewController(videoURL: URL(string: "..."))
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

This doesn't give you a full-screen video with a dismiss button but a sheet modal which can be swiped away instead.

In standard non-SwiftUI Swift, it would seem like the best way would be to present this controller...

```
let controller = PlayerViewController(videoURL: URL(string: "..."))
self.present(controller, animated: true)
```

...but SwiftUI doesn't have a `self.present` as part of it. What would be the best way to present a full-screen video in SwiftUI?

Comment: This answer could help you, you can change the style and presentation mode as you like. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60391281/how-to-present-crossdissolve-view-in-swiftui/60403229#60403229

Comment: Apple added support for full screen views in SwiftUI. It works for me using an UIImagePickerView, so it might work with your AVPlayerView/Controller as well. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64069283/3997690

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/131762

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of sheet I would use the solution with ZStack (probably with custom transition if needed), like below

```
ZStack {
    // ... other your content below

    if showingDetail { // covers full screen above all
       PlayerViewController(videoURL: URL(string: "..."))
         .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
         //.transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom).animation(.default)) // if needed
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes a lot of sense and wish it was clearer in the docs!

Comment: Any advice on how to use this to show full screen and also be able to close video player with a swipe down, also close the player using an X button etc?