# Show UIKit PopUp ViewController in SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

How can I show a UIKit PopUp ViewController in SWiftUI

in UIKit we do it like below

```
let controller  = PopupVC(title: "Alert", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam", icon: nil, buttonTitle: "Close")
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
controller.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
self.present(controller, animated: true)
```

how can we do the same in SwiftUI? I am trying it like below

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isShowingPopup = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow.opacity(0.5)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            Button(action: {
                isShowingPopup.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Click Me")
                    .font(.system(size: 15))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(hex: "1775FF"))
                    .cornerRadius(8)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowingPopup) {
            
            PopupVC(title: "Alert", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam", icon: nil, buttonTitle: "Close").preview()
        }
        
    }
}
```

Where preview is UIViewController extension

```
//MARK: UIViewController
extension UIViewController {
    
  func preview() -> some View {
    struct Wrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
      typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController

      let viewController: UIViewController

      func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        viewController
      }

      func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {

      }
    }
    return Wrapper(viewController: self)
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
  }

}
```

But it does not apply `modalPresentationStyle` and `modalTransitionStyle` to `.overFullScreen` and `.crossDissolve` respectively.

how to achieve this?

here are the end results I am getting.

[image]

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/60403229/5133585 answer your question?

Comment: yes it worked thanks 